# Group values by columns axis=1 dinamically

Tags: python, pandas

I have a matrix df with 70 columns.

```
id  day_1 day_2 day_3 day_4 ... day_69 day_70
1   1     2     4     1         1      1
2   0     0     0     0         0      0
3   0     3     0     0         0      0
4   3     2     1     0         0      3
```

I would like to aggregate the columns  dinamically by [2,7,10, etc.] number of days. I.e. [bi-daily, weekly, ten-daily, etc.]

- E.g. one of the results for aggregation (sum) by 2 days would be a dataframe with 35 columns, see below:

```
id  bi_daily_1 bi_daily_2 ...bi_daily_35 
1   3          5             2      
2   0          0             0      
3   3          0             0      
4   5          1             3
```

where :

`bi_daily_1 = aggregation(day_1, day_2)`

`bi_daily_2 = aggregation(day_3, day_4)` and so on...

Note: Real matrix shape is aprox (2000, 1500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use floor division based on the number of days to determine groups (`df.shape[1]` is the number of columns in the dataframe), then use `groupby` on these groups specifying the axis as 1 (columns).  Then just rename the columns.

```
days = 2
result = df.groupby([x // days for x in range(df.shape[1])], axis=1).sum()
result.columns = [f'bi_daily_{n + 1}' for n in result.columns]
>>> result
    bi_daily_1  bi_daily_2
id                        
1            3           5
2            0           0
3            3           0
4            5           1
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work, using a list comprehension: split the dataframe into pairs of two consecutive columns, use the iloc notation, sum each new dataframe, then concat to get a new dataframe.

```
    day_1   day_2   day_3   day_4
0      1      2     4       1
1      0      0     0       0
2      0      3     0       0
3      3      2     1       0



(pd.concat([df.iloc[:,[i,i+1]]
              .sum(axis=1)
            for i in range(0,df.shape[1],2)],
 axis=1)
.add_prefix('bi_daily_')
 )


  bi_daily_0    bi_daily_1
0   3           5
1   0           0
2   3           0
3   5           1
```